# how i can run a script to another page loaded from jquery load specific tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

The loader

```
$( "#b" ).load( "thepage.html #target" );

<div id="b"></div>
```

thepage.html

```
<div id="target">
<script>
alert('the page');
</script>
hi world
</div>
```

I need  when 'thepage.html' is loaded from the jquery function display the alert

Comment: Your Script is not included in the target `#target` section, so why would it load?

Comment: ready, but equally does not work

Comment: Edited my answer. I hope it helps address your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this:

```
$( "#b" ).load( "thepage.html #target" );

<div id="b"></div>
```

<strike>And you want the JS to execute, you need to have a `#target` like so:</strike>

```
<div id="target">
  <script>
  alert('the page');
  </script>
  hi world
</div>
```

**EDIT**

From the JQuery API:

> If `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, **the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated**,
>   and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will
>   successfully execute.
>
> ```
> $( "#a" ).load( "article.html" );
> ```
>
> However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being
>   loaded into #b are stripped out and not executed:
>
> ```
> $( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );
> ```

You will have to execute the JS once the Load completes. You won't be able to load the script from the page due to security concerns.

Could try this:

```
<div id="target">
  Hello World.
  <div style="display: none;" id="alertMessage">The Page</div>
</div>
```

Then execute like so:

```
$("#b").load("thepage.html #target", function(r, s, x){
    if(s != "error"){
       alert($("#alertMessage").text());
    }
});
```